# Can we use openzeppelin library to make contracts upgrade-able in ETC test net?

Tags: ethereum-classic, openzeppelin, contract-upgrading

I am trying to develop smart contracts to run in the ETC test-net. Beforehand, I am doing some background research and need to know if openzeppelin library is compatible to make things work in ETC  as well.

What solidity version is compatible in the ETC network and is it possible to use openzeppelin to make contracts upgrade-able?

Answer (score 0):

https://ethereumclassic.org/development/porting

> All Web3.js frontend code is compatible with ETC as long as the provider RPC node being pointed to is an ETC instance. No changes to Solidity (.sol) code is necessary, ETH contracts run out of the box on ETC! Development tools like Remix and Truffle also work natively.

**DON'T TRUST. VERIFY**

Ask a computer.

My intuitive feel tells me it should just work, try on testnet first

Comment: Thanks for your information. But what about making in upgradeable with openzeppelin CLI tool?